# My elements are overlapping in css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Hi so I have a flex containers and I named it `NewsSection` that contains another flex container named `NewsTeller` that contains an image and a `h1` and a `p` elements
and I have some javascript code that creates a `NewsTeller` div and appends it to the `NewsSection` container

But on mobile it's overlapping bcuz the paragraph element is pretty big

Here's my css

```
/*
* {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
   background: #171719;
}
body {
    font-size: 15pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
    background: #171719;
}

.Navbar {
   position: sticky;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 75px;
   display: flex;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.NavItems {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15pt;
}
*/

a {
   color: currentColor;
   text-decoration: grey;
   font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
}

#NewsSection {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}




#NewsTeller {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
```

And the live website is here
https://shortglobalnews.netlify.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On #NewsSection remove the set height, this element seems dynamic & is being restricted by the parent's height being explicit.

Remove this property from the wrapper

```
#NewsSection {
 height: 100vh;
}
```

Also, your images would benefit from this CSS property. It helps it crop properly for as big as they are and all being different sizes, to begin with.

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot man it worked